# SharePoint Mobile - Look and Feel

Tags: 2010, mobile

How can I customize the SharePoint mobile pages look and feel by customizing the CSS? Where are the CSS files located that are loaded when the SharePoint renders the mobile pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has an article on how to do this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802539.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862633.aspx

In short, you have to use the SPMobile tag, and embed the css file in it's markup.